# DataTable keeps going back to first page when changing the checked status of checkboxes in other pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have the following code

```
$('.chk_realtor:checked').each(function () {
                    emailarr.push($(this).val());
                    action = "Selected";
                });
```

whenever I click the select all button in any page other than 1st The datatable keeps reverting back to the first page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a **render** property of DataTable configuration.

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',  
      'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable':false,
         'orderable':false,
         'className': 'dt-body-center',
         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' 
                + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
         }
      }],
      'order': [1, 'asc']
   });
```

here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/zL6hcqp2/1/)